# Automatic website tooltips from custom glossary?

Tags: php, jquery, tooltip

I have a PHP website that contains a lot of technical content. I created a glossary for some of the more obscure terms used on the website. I would like tooltips (or hint bubbles, whatever they're called) to be displayed whenever a user hovers over one of these terms.

I found a ton of jQuery extensions that seem to do what I want but they need to be manually linked to each term instance by setting a `span` tag to a specific class.

I want this done automatically. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend doing this server-side. A jQuery plugin will slow the page down when there are many elements on the page.
You might get something like:

```
$content = "<p>Lorem ajax ipsum</p>";

$terms = array(
    'ajax' => 'Asynchronous JavaScript and XML',
);

foreach ($terms as $term => $explained) {
    $content = str_replace($term, '<acronym title="' . htmlspecialchars($explained) . '">' . $term . '</acronym>', $content);
}
```

Comment: +1 for the server side solution. But you still gonna need to add some styling or even a simple JS function to show the tooltip on hover.

Comment: Actually no, browsers automatically use the `title` attribute to show a tooltip on hover.

Answer (score 0):

I built off [sroes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/616859/sroes)' answer, but needed to solve two problems:

- **Partial words**, ie when defining "rap", you do not want to replace it inside "Those raptors"
- **Replacement of self**, ie where a definition of "song" includes the word "rap", it would then be replaced again, leading to definitions on top of definitions.

This example could likely be improved with a regex or some other way to remove the nested foreach loops, suggestions welcome - but keep in mind the serial replacement in stritr.

```
function add_glossary_tooltips($text) {
    global $glossary;
    if(empty($glossary))
        return $text;
    // Create array of replacements, using only individual
    // words surrounded by spaces or other punctuation

    $endings = array(
        '.',
        ' ',
        ',',
        '!',
        '-',
        '?',
        '&',
    );
    $beginnings = array(
        '-',
        ' ',
    );
    $replacements = array();
    foreach ($glossary as $entry) {
        $clean_defintion = htmlentities(strip_tags($entry['definition']), ENT_QUOTES);
        $replacement = "<abbr
                class='tooltip'
                title='".$clean_defintion."'
            >"
            .$entry['glossary_word']
            ."</abbr>";
        foreach ($endings as $ending) {
            foreach ($beginnings as $beginning) {
                $replacements[$beginning.$entry['glossary_word'].$ending] = $beginning.$replacement.$ending;
            }
        }
    }

    $text = stritr($text, $replacements);

    return $text;
}
```

This is supported by a custom case-insensitive strstr. (Not my work)

```
function stritr($string, $one = NULL, $two = NULL){
/*
stritr - case insensitive version of strtr
Author: Alexander Peev
Posted in PHP.NET
*/
    if(  is_string( $one )  ){
        $two = strval( $two );
        $one = substr(  $one, 0, min( strlen($one), strlen($two) )  );
        $two = substr(  $two, 0, min( strlen($one), strlen($two) )  );
        $product = strtr(  $string, ( strtoupper($one) . strtolower($one) ), ( $two . $two )  );
        return $product;
    }
    else if(  is_array( $one )  ){
        $pos1 = 0;
        $product = $string;
        while(  count( $one ) > 0  ){
            $positions = array();
            foreach(  $one as $from => $to  ){
                if(   (  $pos2 = stripos( $product, $from, $pos1 )  ) === FALSE   ){
                    unset(  $one[ $from ]  );
                }
                else{
                    $positions[ $from ] = $pos2;
                }
            }
            if(  count( $one ) <= 0  )break;
            $winner = min( $positions );
            $key = array_search(  $winner, $positions  );
            $product = (   substr(  $product, 0, $winner  ) . $one[$key] . substr(  $product, ( $winner + strlen($key) )  )   );
            $pos1 = (  $winner + strlen( $one[$key] )  );
        }
        return $product;
    }
    else{
        return $string;
    }
}/* endfunction stritr */
```